# Why is the weight of the hanging part of the chain equal to the friction on the remaining part of the chain kept on the table?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image]

In order to prevent the chain from slipping, the friction on the part of the chain kept on the table should be equal to the weight of the hanging part of the chain. Why is that so?

Comment: why do you think it is incorrect or needs attention ?

Comment: @Ankit I just didn't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: This problem might be more realistic if posed with a rope or pulley. The forces on links of chain passing over a sharp edge can be complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the horizontal forces acting on the part of the chain kept on the table. There are two: friction $F_f$ (acting to the left) and tension $F_T$ (acting to the right). For the forces to be balanced, it is necessary that $|F_f| = |F_T|$.

Now let's consider the vertical forces acting on the hanging part of the chain. Say this part of the chain has mass $m_2$. There are two forces: gravity $m_2g$ (acting downwards) and tension $F_T$ (acting upwards). For the forces to be balanced, it is necessary that $|m_2g| = |F_T|$.

Why do these tensions have equal magnitude? Essentially, the connection between the two parts of the chain "redirects" the tension force along the direction of the chain.

Thus $|F_f| = |m_2g|$.

Comment: Thank you so much!